# Determine whether the function is surjective or injective or both or neither

Tags: real-analysis, functions

[image]

Please help me with this problem i am not having any idea

Comment: Please show me some work so that I can appropriately help you; otherwise, I have no idea how to help you.

Comment: @clayton.. i am really sorry i didt get idea for this problem

Comment: @rajendra You should at least describe what's giving you trouble. Tell us what you know, and tell us what you don't know. You're not going to get much help unless you've shown you've made an effort.

Comment: @Alex...for show one -one  u should prove either if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x+1=x_2$ but i dont know  hwo to processed same as the for onto we choose a y such that f(x)=y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x_1)= f(x_2)=(p,q)$

If $q=0$, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both even and $\frac{x_1}{2}=\frac{x_2}{2}$, hence $x_1=x_2$.

Similarly, if $q=1$, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both odd and $\frac{x_1-1}{2}=\frac{x_2-1}{2}$, and hence $x_1=x_2$.

Hence $f$ is injective.

Now suppose $(p,q) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \{0,1\}$,

if $q=0$, notice that $2p\in \mathbb{Z}$ and even, $f(2p)=(\frac{2p}{2},0)=(p,0)$.

if $q=1$,notice that $2p+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and odd and $f(2p+1)=(\frac{2p+1-1}{2},1)=(p,1)$.

Hence $f$ is surjective.